# Please say about size inferred

Tags: swift, storyboard

I am fresher in Swift language. If I take the size of inferred instead of any other, it will effect in constraints? In which size I should do designing is there any proper method for constraints.

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: refer this also https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inferred** size means that the Storyboard *infers* the scene size according to its super-scene size (the parent's size).

If you have a scene that is the size of an iPad and then you add a new scene to your storyboard and create a segue to it, it will **automatically resize** to the same size as the iPad scene (where the segue originates from).

**Freeform** ignores the above rule and you're able to size the scene as you like, in the utility pane on the right.

This setting **does not** affect constraints, and *how* the view is displayed on actual devices. For that, you need to use [**AutoLayout**](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/proportional-spacing-with-auto-layout/) and constraints.